# Excel if formula expression

Tags: google-sheets

I have two lists in google spreadsheet table . In second table I have range of dates and values like: Wednesday 1 aug, thursday 2 aug ....
I need to put value into first table if value in B35 (which is wednesday 1 aug) from second where it is wednesday 1 aug too. So I can change date and have new value in first list.

Comment: I appreciate the argument that Excel is a form of programming, but pragmatically you may get better tips on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel)

Comment: An image showing what you have and what you want will help, as I am confused.

Comment: @SolarMike can't find how to insert image here. I have a list which has range of values. Also I have a cell which shows the date like: Wed, 1 Aug. I am editing it manually. Second list has values for each date in columns: for Wed 1 Aug, Thur 2 Aug ... I need to edit data on first list from second  based on date I've putted into my cell

Comment: [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).  You can find info on how to add pictures here...

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax for an if statement :

=if ( test, then_true, otherwise_value )
hope you find this somewhat helpful